# Regex not performing as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this bit of code that i *think* should be detecting if the supplied string consists only of any number of spaces, followed by a comma, followed by any number of spaces:

```
if(str.match("/^[ ]*,[ ]*$/")) {
  //do something
}
```

And the following string does not match " , ".   In fact, no number of spaces before or after a comma in a string that only consists of spaces and a single comma will match.  I think I may be confused with my syntax and it just hasn't clicked.

I have also tried replacing the regex with these with no luck:

```
"/^[\s]*[,][\s]*$/"
"/^[\s]*,[\s]*$/"
"/^[ ]*[,][ ]*$/"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: **Try it again without the double quotes.**

Comment: You have a string, not a regular expression. The string will be converted to a regular expression, but it will contain the `/` characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't quote the RegExes. You're trying to match the actual, literal RegEx text that way.  Try:

```
if (str.match(/^\s*,\s*$/))
{
  // whatever
}
```

to match any whitespace characters, or

```
if (str.match(/^ *, *$/))
```

to match spaces only.

Comment: Thumbs up for avoiding unnecessary square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript the regex doesn't need to be quoted...

```
if(str.match(/^[ ]*,[ ]*$/)) {
 //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be, you are passing a string to `match` instead of a regex, also use `\s` for `space` instead of `[ ]`

```
if(str.match(/^[ ]*,[ ]*$/)) {
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put quotes around your regex in Javascript/jQuery -- remove them and your first attempt should work fine (it does at this RegExr link: http://regexr.com?35v18)

So, what you need is `str.match(/^[ ]*,[ ]*$/)`

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer already posted, but if you are using jQuery, you can also use

```
if ($.trim(str) === ",") {
  //do something
}
```

(that will strip all whitespace from the beginning and end, not just spaces)